# Is there a container facade in Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, containers

I'm learning how to use iterator_facade to hide some boilerplate of iterator implementation. In my current use case I'm wrapping another container (from .NET code, actually) so I need the begin(), end(), typedefs, etc. At a minimum I want the resulting type to work with BOOST_FOREACH. Is there a convenient thing in boost to simplify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap a pair of iterators from the given container in a [`boost::iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) from the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/index.html) library.

Comment: What's the "given" container? The one I'm wrapping is a .NET container.

Comment: That doesn't help with all the `begin`, `end`, `typedef`s n stuff. Take a look at `iterator_facade`, it eases the implementation of iterators *greatly*.

Comment: @Xeo : The linked-to class synopsis clearly shows implementations of said typedefs as well as `begin` and `end`.

Comment: @Matt : In this case, the iterators being wrapped are the ones you created with `iterator_facade` rather than those of a container; `iterator_range` nets you `begin` and `end` implementations necessary to use `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah! I know understand what you mean.

Comment: Hmm, I need the container to hold on to the wrapped .NET container, but it's neat a method so I accepted it anyway. I could inherit from iterator_range but without a virtual dtor it's dangerous. :(

Comment: `iterator_facade` is a class to inherit from. Do you suggest to derive a (custom) container from `boost::iterator_range`? (it may make sense, I never tried).